# How to disable the button if Edittext is empty and pass the Edittext input to another activity in android studio?

Tags: android

I am creating a game and the players need to put their name into the EditText and pass it to another screen, but the button must be disabled while the EditText is empty. And it will become enabled if the players enter their name and when they press Enter, it will proceed to another screen welcoming the player.

Answer (score 0):

You can add text changed listener to your edit text and if user entered the name enable the button.

```java
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     // enable your button here.
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
   {}

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
   {}
});
```

For passing this value into another activity you can add bundle to your intent:

```java
  Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putString("playerName", name); // Player name
  intent.putExtras(b);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Stackoverflow.

The solution ,in fact , is quite simple.

- First, add text watcher to your EditText

  ```
   TextWatcher textWatcher= new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       String inputFromUser= editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();

       yourButton.setEnabled( !inputFromUser.isEmpty() );
   }
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }
  ```

  };
- Then you just need to add this TextWatcher to your EditText like
  following.

  ```
     yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
  ```
- Finally, Add a clickListener to the button.

Note: If you are using kotlin you can also use ktx-extentions

```
yourEditText.doAfterTextChanged { inputText -> 
    // do the same proccess here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer in points below:

1. Please do not disable the button if `EditText` is empty. It gives inconsistent feel to the user and may confuse your user base.
   Instead show an error message if they leave the `EditText` empty and click on continue button.
2. Add attribute `app:errorEnabled="true"` inside your `EditText` xml code.
3. Then inside your Activity add following condition:

```
continue_button.setOnClickListener {
    val userInput = edit_text.text!!
    if (userInput != null && userInput.length >= /*some number*/) {
        edit_text.error = null
        // Allow Continue Operation
    } else {
        edit_text.error = "Please Enter Valid Username"
    }
}
```

4. You can use Intent to launch Another activity and pass the data from your `EditText`.

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("USERNAME_KEY", userInput) //Here userInput  is the data from Edit Text
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
youtEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        yourButtonbutton.isEnabled = s.toString().trim().isNotEmpty()
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    }
})
```